# Unity: как реализовать уничтожение трейла при соприкосновении с ним объекта?

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать так, чтобы трейл уничтожался при соприкосновении гейм обджекта с трейлом от `TrailRenderer`?
К примеру: куб движется вперед и оставляет за собой трейл, далее куб движется назад и при соприкосновении с созданными трейлами - уничтожает их.
Как сделать это?

Answer (score 0):

Очень маловероятно что трейл на это способен в принципе с любого рода костылями. Ведь это просто рендерер, ты никак не можешь проверить колижн трейла с обьектом.

Возможно, подойдет альтернативное решение через частицы (Particles). Тогда можно дестроить частицы на OnParticleCollision и получишь нужный результат.

Comment: "ты никак не можешь проверить колижн трейла с обьектом" - с чего вдруг? Как минимум мешу трейла можно использовать в виде меши для коллайдера.

Comment: как это сделать? можно поподробнее?

Comment: вешаешь компонент частиц, настраиваешь их, вешаешь на твоего плеера скрипт в котором дестроишь все что попадется под руку в методе OnParticleCollision(). Или пробуешь пойти методом который предложил Riot -- повесить на меш трейла mеshCollider и  убивать ближайшие полигоны на OnCollisionEnter(). Но что-то хз что из этого выйдет. Может что-то и вылетит, а может и вылезут какие артефакты поведения...